# which channel of ubuntu touch is better for daily use in nexus 4 RC or Stable or Devel

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I am really confused of the channels provided by the ubuntu touch, and i need to know which channel can be used for daily uses and can be updated if possible

Answer (score 1):

If you're not wanting to do much in the way of debugging you're probably going to want to stick to Stable. You might also benefit by reading up on some of the terms you're going to run into using actively developed software:

[Ubuntu Touch Image Channels](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/image-channels/)

[Software release life cycle - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle)